# Repetition in updating rows in MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to update a column in already exists MySQL table. The values must be read from a text file, and then they must be inserted into the specified column.

I have tried the following:

```
int counter=0;
        while((fileLine=in.readLine())!=null) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Line read is: "+fileLine);

                //execute db insertion
                try {
                    //insert in the database
                    Query= "update db.table set col4=?";    //database
                    preparedStmt3 = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query); 
                    preparedStmt3.setString (1, fileLine);
                    preparedStmt3.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Complete update statement for row: "+counter);
                    counter++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("DB_Error:_"+ e.toString());
                }

        } //end while loop
```

I have tried to output `fileLine` value and it seems correct and change correctly with every loop round. But, after I run the program and check the database, I find that the value inserted is the last line only (and this repeated in all records, it is not what I am supposed to do, which is insert every line in records consequently). what is the cause for this problem ?

EDIT:
The text file contains the following lines:
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff

The run output after I added some `printline` statements to see debug is as the following:

[image]

while the DB contains the last line inserted only

[image]

Comment: It seems your column has no relation to the rest of the columns in the table? Then you should probably separate out to different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
Connection conn = ConnectionBean.getInstance().getDBConnection();
int counter=0;
String fileLine;
BufferedReader in;
String query1 = "select id from test"; // get all the id's from the table you wanna do  the update
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // store them in an arraylist
try {
PreparedStatement stmnt = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    al.add(rs.getInt("id"));
}
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    int h=1;
    while((fileLine=in.readLine())!=null && al.size()>0)  
    {   

        String query="UPDATE chaitu.test SET col=? WHERE id="+h ;
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        statement.setString(1, fileLine);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        h++;
    } //end while loo


} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

Comment: But I don't know the id. I want the update to be done for all records. Starting from the first one to the last one without specifying any number. The id I have is auto increment, I deleted many records, so the numbers are not consecutive.

Comment: Still nothing changed. Only the last line read from the file is the one inserted in all records.

Comment: @JuryA it would be great if you posted the database screenshot.

Comment: chaitanya10: It does not work. What i need to be inserted in col4 is: in record 1 I need: "aaa", In record 2: "bbb", in record 3: "ccc" ... etc.

Comment: @JuryA if you want to insert "aaa" into pk_hex at row1 and "bbb" into pk_Hex at row2 then you will have to specify the where clause as in the update. without that (in your code) all fields rows at col pk_hex will be updated with "fff". you should provide a where cluase for sure

Comment: Ok, how can I do this??? I have a lot of rows with different ids, how can this be done ? Even if I assumed that the id is consecutive like: 1,2,3, ..etc. How can I make this in the query ??

Comment: @JuryA u have to loop throu the rows that you wanna update and provide the where clause a simple update w/o where clause would update all the rows...

Comment: chaitanya10: I got the idea that I need to use where clause. But, can you provide me with a code to clarify how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you help in writing the query: `Query= "update test.pk set pk_hex=? where pk_id= ????? ";` How can I specify the pk_id value to move through the whole table??

Comment: chaitinya10, when using a `PreparedStatement` it is better to leave the creation of the PS (which is expensive) outside the loop, and inside the loop just set the values for the parameters and execute the query.

Comment: @SJuan76 i know that. my initial code was the same. i changed it later as the OP wanted to update the col in every row onn each iteration. i know this approach is a disaster and we have to use batched updates to do it

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL does not add a WHERE clause to specify which rows to update. So, at every iteration, all the records in the column have their `col4` field updated to the value. The last one is the update that remains.

Comment: I dont have any condition. I want to update all records. My file has lines = number of records. I need to insert each line value in the record starting from the first to last. I have id column that is primary key and auto increment, but I deleted many values so the id number is not consecutive. I prefer to not put any conditions. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please tell me how to update all rows automatically. Assume row1 has id=1, row2 has id=2, .. etc. How can I automate this in the query ??

Comment: Add to the SQL ` where id=?`, and set this parameter with a counter variable that you increase in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you are using update query to insert values. Use

```
INSERT INTO db.table (col4) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: This does not work. it will insert new records. I need to insert the values I read from the text file into already available records.